# docker-compose ports not exposed as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm developing a Magento site using a [Docker local environment](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/cloud/docker/docker-development.html).

I've installed the [Sass blank theme](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-theme-blank-sass) and [frontools](https://github.com/SnowdogApps/magento2-frontools). Now I'm trying to get [browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) working.

I'm doing this inside the `cli` image, because that's where I initially setup gulp prior to trying my hand at browsersync.

Here are the respective configs

docker-compose.yml

```
cli:
  image: 'magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.1-cli-scss2'
  ports:
    - '3001:3001'
  depends_on:
    - db
    - redis
    - elasticsearch
    - rabbitmq
  volumes:
    - '~/.cache/composer:/root/.composer/cache'
    - '.:/var/www/magento:rw'
  volumes_from:
    - appdata
  env_file:
    - ./docker/global.env
    - ./docker/config.env
```

gulpfile.js

```
gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy: 'hz.moxune.net',
        port: 3001,
        open: false,
        notify: false,
    });

    gulp.watch([
        '../../../app/design/frontend/Magento/my-theme/styles/**/*.*.scss',
        ['sass']
    ]);
});
```

It seems to be working on the host machine, which is to say if I run `lynx http://cli-container-ip:3001`, the site loads. However it is not exposed over the network (the server is on my LAN, not my local machine). So despite having

```
ports:
    - '3001:3001'
```

after starting up the stack with `docker-compose up`, running `docker ps` reveals the PORTS section of the listing is empty...

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                      NAMES
93b73452fb18        magento/magento-cloud-docker-php:7.1-cli-scss2   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   3 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds                                                   magento_cli_run_63
```

Seems I'm not doing something right with the `ports` specification?

Comment: That container doesn't look like it was created with `docker-compose up`. The name looks wrong for that.

Comment: @BMitch I modified the original cli image with `docker commit` and ever since then the container doesn't start until I run `docker-compose run cli bash`, which I thought was strange. Any idea why it doesn't start with `docker-compose` now that I've changed the image?

Comment: You'd need to show logs and error messages for us to help debug that. I'd also recommend against `docker commit` as a method to update images, it's very error prone. Use a Dockerfile and `docker build` instead. From your existing compose file, there are lots of potential issues. It looks like a v1 syntax which is deprecated, along with `depends_on`, and `volumes_from`.

Comment: Ok thanks, think you've pointed me in a direction where I can start looking at least. The docker-compose file is provided by magento. I'll take a look at the logs and see what I can figure out.

Comment: I see, the cli container is starting via docker-compose, then exiting. Somehow it must have changed slightly when I did`docker commit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your port is not published because you did not run `docker-compose up`. A `docker-compose run` command does not use all the service specifications in the compose file.

Comment: I built a new image from a Dockerfile and it's working, thank you sir!